# How do I avoid losing magicka so quickly while being attacked with lighting spells?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I currently have a level 14 mage character in Skyrim, but I am unable to defeat other magic-using enemies when they use Sparks even when I am dual-casting Lightning Bolt at them!

My magicka is *completely* drained by their attack and they finish me off while I am waiting for it to recharge. My character's maximum magicka is 240. Would trying to get magic resistance or absorption be a viable option? I'm also only using robes at the moment, so I could switch to light or heavy armor if that would help.

Answer (score 5):

Magika regenerating items help a lot with running out of juice mid-battle. Take on a few of the mage's guild quests to stock up (you can equip a robe, necklace and circlet / mask all at once).

Additionally, spend perks on destruction magic, which will decrease the amount of magika you burn. And don't forget to keep a couple of restore magika potions in your pocket for when you end up in a tight spot.

Comment: Im pretty sure everyone keeps all the potions they ever find in case they end up in a tight spot.

Comment: Yep, you're right @user1337, I usually end up with dozens of potions "just in case". Worth mentioning though.

Answer (score 2):

Although **Regenerate Magicka** is undoubtfully helpfull, if you are going to go fully into destruction magic, then it would be better to choose [lower destruction spells cost](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Master_Robes#Fortify_Destruction_with_Regenerate_Magicka).

Furthermore, if enchanting level is high enough, it may be possible to craft a full suite of **Fortify destruction** apparel that will void magicka requirements of any destruction spell. That can spoil immersion however.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading destruction magic perks will definitely help, but to use magic effectively I have found only two viable options:

1. Enchant many (if not all) of your armour parts with [Regenerate Magicka](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Regenerate_Magicka).
2. Use a backup weapon, in this case I would suggest a bow (or crossbow if you have the Dawnguard DLC). This is my preferred route as I frequently play as a Mage/Rouge type. Obviously this won't be an option if you want to be pure Mage for RPG purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised the other answers haven't mentioned what's probably the most powerful Destruction perk for a glass-cannon-type destruction magic user: `Impact`. The *Stagger* it causes is in effect a stun, which prevents the enemy from doing anything for several seconds. Against a single opponent, it's pretty easy to keep them stun-locked* (against multiple opponents it's also possible but gets more and more difficult), that way you'll prevent them from casting those oh-so-annoying mana drain spells on you.

At lower levels, while you don't have all the *lower-spells-costs* enchants or access to the frost minion yet, another thing you can do is have a follower to tank for you. They can soak up pretty big chunks of damage while you blast away and drink potions.

---

*Warning: can get pretty boring at higher levels, either stop doing this or try pulling more enemies when it starts getting too easy

Comment: thanks. Impact does sound useful and i'm slowly approaching higher levels(at 18 now). And it's true I didn't use followers at all since I was afraid they would use potential chance for gaining exp. Wouldn't they? By getting in the way and not letting you kill anyone?

Comment: The amount of skillups that a follower takes away from you is negligible in general, doubly so for a mage that doesn't gain armor skillups from being hit. Also remember that Skyrim is not a leveling race: enemies scale as you level up; you won't have to fight ancient dragons at level 10.